# Passing an inconstant default parameter to a C# method

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

I want to pass an object as the default value for `defUserInfo` method, but It's not possible since it's not a `compile-time constant`. Is there any other way to make this work?

```
private static CustomerIdentifications defUserInfo = new CustomerIdentifications
{
    CustomerID = "1010",
    UniqueIdentifier = "1234"
};
public static HttpResponseMessage GenerateToken<T>(T userInfo = defUserInfo)
{
   // stuff
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an overloaded method:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage GenerateToken()
{
    return GenerateToken(defUserInfo);
}
public static HttpResponseMessage GenerateToken<T>(T userInfo)
{
   // stuff
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a more robust approach than using magic values

Answer (score 1):

If `CustomerIdentifications` were a struct, you could kind of simulate default values, by using struct properties instead of fields:

```
using System;

struct CustomerIdentifications
{
    private string _customerID;
    private string _uniqueIdentifier;

    public CustomerIdentifications(string customerId, string uniqueId)
    {
      _customerID = customerId;
      _uniqueIdentifier = uniqueId;
    }

    public string CustomerID { get { return _customerID ?? "1010"; } }
    public string UniqueIdentifier { get { return _uniqueIdentifier ?? "1234"; } }
}

class App
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var id = GenerateToken<CustomerIdentifications>();
    Console.WriteLine(id.CustomerID);
    Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueIdentifier);
  }

  public static T GenerateToken<T>(T userInfo = default(T))
  {
    // stuff
    return userInfo;
  }
}
```